# Как в одном запросе получить значение ячейки таблицы и сразу изменить его?

Tags: mysql, sql

Я храню счетчик в таблице, мне нужно узнать его значение и увеличить на 1, но чтобы в этот процесс никто не вклинился. Подскажите как такое реализовать?

Comment: `UPDATE \`table\` SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE ....`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это понятно, но так ведь мне не возвращается значение counter

Comment: мне нужно обновить и получить что там было или стало

Comment: `получить значение ячейки таблицы и сразу изменить его` != `изменить значение ячейки таблицы и сразу получить его` :)  надо чётче формулировать)

Comment: Вы меняете фиксированно одну запись и получить хотите значение из этой единственной записи ?

Comment: ) хорошо а какой вариант можно сделать  получить -> изменить или изменить -> получить? мне больше первый нужен,

Comment: @Mike да.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В момент обновления поля получаем старое значение в переменную. После выполнения обновления получаем значение этой переменной:

```
update table
   set counter = (@old:= counter)+1
 where ...;
select @old
```

Способ может работать только в случае изменения строго одной записи. Если по условиям под обновление попадут несколько строк то в переменной окажется значение из последней обновленной строки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61658/discussion-on-answer-by-mike--------).